# Java program is faster on Windows than Ubuntu

Tags: java, windows, performance, postgresql, ubuntu

I have written a program in Java which operates on a Postgres-DB.

The problem is, that the execution of the program takes 4058ms on Windows 7 and 11250ms on Ubuntu 12.10.

- Windows machine: Core i7 with 4x1.6 GHz and 4GB Ram
- Ubuntu machine: Xeon E3-1230 with 4x3.3GHZ and 32GB Ram

I have separately tested java and the db, but the Ubuntu machine is always faster.

Measured execution times:

1. Java Program with a lot of loops and no println: Windows 9601ms, Ubuntu 2851ms
2. Postgres function which inserts 1.000.000 entries: Windows: 6045ms, Ubuntu: 2136ms

I tested the server with OpenJDK and Oracle Java, whereby OpenJDK is 10% faster.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You'd think the opposite would be true, is Ubuntu running on a java driven VM?

Comment: Profile your application and/or add some logging to find precisely where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: Ubuntu is running on a rented root server (dedicated server)

Comment: Is the Postgress DB local to both machines and is it's access to data the same. i.e. can you rule out the database as slowing the application?

Comment: Can you profile the application to see what it is doing?  The CPU profile for the machines should be quite different in sampling mode. That should tell you where it is spending more time.

Comment: I don't understand you: in the first sentence you say the Windows computer is faster but the "measured execution times" clearly show the Ubuntu machine to be faster

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It looks to me that the measured execution times appear to be from separate benchmarks the OP is making on a test program.  The actual program runs slower on Ubuntu, the benchmark programs run faster on Ubuntu.  That is the strange part.

Comment: It's very difficult to compare these timing results without knowing more about what the application is doing and what else may be running next to it in both cases. How data is cached (and how the cache is flushed) may have some influence, whether you're using the same dataset too. (Sometimes running the same long PostgreSQL queries twice almost consecutively requires very different execution times). More importantly, looking at `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the queries run by your application could show something useful (like some disk operation in one case, or perhaps relying on an index).

Comment: The databases are quite the same, both are localhost and the inserted date is the same.

Comment: "Quite the same" doesn't necessarily mean anything. They might not have the same indexes, not been vacuumed in the same way. Are you using the same versions of PostgreSQL on both machines? Even if you dump the DB from one and restore it on the other machine, the state of the indexes or statistics might not be the same, which could impact performance.

Comment: I dumped the data from the Server and restored it on my local Postgres-DB on Windows.

Windows: PostgreSQL 9.3.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1600, 64-bit
//   Ubuntu: PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu8) 4.8.1, 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is passing the '-client' option to the JVM.  The JVM can run in two different modes: 'client' and 'server'.  Server mode means that certain optimizations will be done under the assumption that the JVM will be up for a long time (hours, days, or even weeks).  'client' mode means that optimizations will be made under the assumption that this is a typical "start, do some stuff, exit" type process.

Which mode is enabled by default depends on your installation.  When you install a JVM onto a machine, the installer examines the specs of the machine to try and figure out if it is a server type machine, or a client machine.  If it sees a bunch of RAM, it may decide that this machine is being used as a server and make the default mode 'server' when what you really want is 'client' for this type of process.  (Your Windows machine is probably configured to run in client mode.)

So to do a true benchmark test, you want to make sure both JVMs are running in the same mode.  The best way to guarantee that is to manually pass either the '-client' or '-server' JVM argument when invoking the java command.

Comment: Note that with 64bit JVMs (at least the one from Oracle) there is no client VM any more.

Comment: Good point - and brings up another good thing for the OP to check: are the JVM's you are using on both machines equivalent in terms of 32/64 bit, java version, etc?

Comment: Windows: java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

// Ubuntu: java version "1.7.0_55"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.4.7) (7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1~0.13.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)